# Maven не видит зависимости

Tags: java, maven

Установил java, maven.

команды java -version, echo %JAVA_HOME%, mvn -version из командной строки отрабатывают.

но когда создаю проект maven в IJ idea все зависимости красные (именно version) и все plugins подчеркнуты.

запуск clean выводит

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.472 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-08T18:30:08+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.84.215] failed: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

причем сразу после создания нового проекта

```
Plugins
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4
```

отмечены красным

Comment: без кофе не гадаю

Comment: mvn clean install ? в Idea стоит автоимпорт зависимостей?

Comment: при запуске отчистки выпадает ошибка что выше. а мне кажется что тут с сеткой какие то проблемы, м.б. стоят фильтры и нужно прокси как то настроить. буду у админа спрашивать. а как можно прокси в мавене настроить? автоимпорт да включен.

Answer (score 2):

на будущее кто тоже столкнется с админами которые блокируют сеть и у котого не тянутся зависимости. решение такое. прописываем репозиторий в самом помнике в ручную. ставим версию 2 или 3.

```
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```